# Magento email bouncing back as no email address

Tags: email, magento, magento-1.7

I have a 'guest' checkout option on a Magento store, whenever I complete a transaction the "Order Confirmation" email that it sends out is always being returned.

Obviously the email address itself is being saved in the onepage checkout (otherwise the inline validation will display errors).

On the sales_flat_order table I can see the following columns are all NULL after an order has been placed:

```
customer_email,
customer_firstname,
customer_lastname
```

The odd thing is on the vagrant box (which should be near enough identical) the 3 columns above all have values in them when I go through the exact same process.

I cannot be sure what is happening, but in a nutshell it would seem that this customer_email for whatever reason isn't be saved to the sales_flat_order table & in turn causing this email to return as undelivered.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of where the logic is for the 'Order Confirmation' email can be found within the Magento system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it - there was a core file that had been edited and was setting this customer email value to null...

Answer (score 1):

Order.php from `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/` to `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/`

And

create function `getCustomerEmail()` and code this function

```
public function getCustomerEmail() {
    if(empty($this->getCustomerEmail())) {
        $this->setCustomerEmail($this->getBillingAddress()->getEmail());
    } else {
        $this->setCustomerEmail($this->getCustomerEmail());
    }
}
```